# Syntax to recognize the contents of a cell as a filename

Tags: vba, excel

I have written an Excel macro to copy pdf files from a source folder to a destination folder. I am now trying to incorporate a Do Loop into the macro so I can move multiple files, each of which are identified in a separate cell. Also, the quantity of files to be moved will vary.

When I use the command line

```
sFile = Range("G14").Value & ".pdf"
```

it does copy the file listed in cell G14 to the destination folder. However, I am having no luck using the `Do Loop` and `sFiles = Cells (I,7)` to increment through the series of filenames that I want to move. The macro bombs out on the final step.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Sub Copying_File()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    I = 8
        Do
            I = I + 1
            If Cells(I, 7) = "zzzz" Then Cells(I, 8) = "Transfer of Files Complete"
            If Cells(I, 7) = "zzzz" Then Exit Do
'Declare Variables
            Dim FSO
            Dim sFile As String
            Dim sSFolder As String
            Dim sDFolder As String

'This is Your File Name which you want to Copy
            sFile = Cells(I, 7).Value & ".pdf"

'Change to match the source folder path
            sSFolder = "I:\PatschB\ZZZ Source\"

'Change to match the destination folder path
            sDFolder = "I:\PatschB\ZZZ Destination\"

'Create Object
            Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Copying File to Destination Folder
            FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder

        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to qualify the cell? What does debug.print for sfile say? Might want to add `as object` after `dim FSO`. And usually you increment at end of loop.

Comment: you also need to move the creation of your FSO object out of your loop.  You only need to create this once instead of how you are doing it now, with each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`CopyFile` requires two *full* paths - both should include the file name

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder
```

with this line:

```
FSO.CopyFile sSFolder & sFile, sDFolder
```